# How to force a change with Angular @Input?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent and child component. The child sets an attribute, but if a control is used in the parent then I'd like it to override the child value. My problem is that the value in the parent may not change, and no 'on change' event is called.

The parent component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  aggregate = true;
```

The child component also has an 'aggregate' property

```
export class IssuerTypeIssuerCountStackedBarComponent extends BondsChart implements BondsChartInteract, OnInit, OnChanges {
 @Input() aggregate = false;
```

The child property is linked to the parent

```
<app-issuer-type-issuer-count-stacked-bar *ngIf="series === 'Number of Issuers'"
                                          [aggregate]="aggregate"
</app-issuer-type-issuer-count-stacked-bar>
```

The aggregate value can be set to equal true in the child by using a toggle.
If a year in the parent is then selected, the aggregate value should be reset to false.

e.g.

```
@Input() set year(value: (string | number)) {
if (value) {
  this.aggregate = true;
  this._year = value;
  if (Number(value)) {
    this.aggregate = false;
  }
}
```

}

However, since 'aggregate' in the parent is initially false, then set to true on the child component, setting aggregate to false does not trigger a change at the parent level.

The result is that the aggregate value remains as true at the child level.

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChildren solves this

In the parent component mark each child component

```
<app-issuer-type-deal-count-stacked-bar #bondChart 
                                        [aggregate]="aggregate"
</app-issuer-type-deal-count-stacked-bar>
```

Create a list of these components using @ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren('bondChart') bondCharts: QueryList<any>;
```

Specifically call the property/setter

```
if (Number(value)) {
  this.aggregate = false;
  this.bondCharts.forEach(chart => chart.aggregate = false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand right now the child component is getting correct attribute value from parent. What you want to achieve is to change some parent's property if child aggregate value is change within the child component. What you need in here is custom @Output event

In child component

```
@Output() aggregateChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

toggleChange(){
   this.aggregateChanged.emit('any value you want to emit')
}
```

In parent component

```
   <app-issuer-type-deal-count-stacked-bar #bondChart [aggregate]="aggregate" (aggregateChanged)="anyFunction($event)"
    </app-issuer-type-deal-count-stacked-bar>
```

and then implement whatever logic you want in anyFunction(valueEmitedFromChild).

Comment: Other way around. Parent needs to reset the child. This works well if you have the control in the child. Then emit to the parent and then copy that to children - if the value changes.